# If $gcd(m,n)=1$, prove that $u_{n}u_{m}$ divides $u_{mn}$ for all $m,n \geq 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $gcd(m,n)=1$, prove that $u_{n}u_{m}$ divides $u_{mn}$ for all $m,n \geq 1$.

$u_{1}=u_{2}=1$,  $u_{n}=u_{n-1}+u_{n-2}$ for $n \geq 3$

Comment: Well-known property of Fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1) If $a|b$, then $u_a$ divides $u_b$. In particular $u_m,u_n|u_{mn}$

2) If $(m,n)=1$, then $(u_m,u_n)=1$. Use the Euclidean algorithm to show this.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes. Fixed it.